# Sails.js: Retrieving URL parameter after redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, cas, sails.js

I'm trying to implement CAS into my login system, but I'm stuck on how to retrieve the "ticket". Basically, the ticket is returned in the URL as a parameter but I can't figure out how to parse it out.

Here is my attempted code:

```
login: function(req, res) {
  if (req.session.authenticated) {
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  } else {
    var https = require('https');
    var url = require('url');

    var cas_url = 'https://auth-test.test.edu';
    var login_service = '/cas/login';
    var validation_service = '/cas/validate';
    var service = 'https://localhost:1337';

    res.redirect(cas_url + login_service + '?service=' + service);
    console.log(req.headers);
  }
}
```

After redirecting to my specified URL, the CAS server redirects back to (with sample ticket):
`https://localhost:1337/?ticket=ST-10247-Qn0BuiSHob1dxcjODDku-cas-t1`

Any ideas on how to optimize my code or retrieve the ticket somehow? Thanks!

EDIT: 
For validation now, see comment below on selected answer:

```
index: function(req, res) {
  var ticket = req.param('ticket');

  if (req.session.authenticated) {
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  } else if (ticket) {
    var https = require('https');
    var options = {
      cas_url: 'https://auth-test.berkeley.edu',
      login: '/cas/login',
      validate: '/cas/validate',
      service: 'http://localhost:1337'
    };
    // redirect to validate URL
    res.redirect(options.cas_url + options.validate 
      + '?service=' + options.service + '&ticket=' + ticket);
  } else {
    res.view({
      title: 'Home'
    });
  }
}
```

If the validation passes through the body will have two lines:
    `yes`
    `username`

If the validation does not pass through, the HTML will only display one line:
    `no`

How to I parse each line of the displayed HTML page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create an *index route*, point it to a controller action, and retrieve the token in that action.  For example, in `/config/routes.js`, add:

```
'/': 'HomeController.index'
```

then in `/api/controllers/HomeController`:

```
index: function (req, res) {

   // req.param will contain any route params, body params or
   // query string params
   var ticket = req.param('ticket');

   return res.send("The ticket is: " + ticket);

}
```

`https://localhost:1337/` will then point at that code, assuming you have SSL set up correctly on your server!

Comment: Thanks! If I need to validate a ticket, I have to redirect it again to the validation URL, which simply displays a "yes" or a "no" on a blank HTML page. How do I parse the HTML page to retrieve the "yes" or "no"? Edited above to include code sample.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: 
If the validation passes through the body will have two lines:
yes
username

If the validation does not pass through, the HTML will only display one line:
no

Comment: This seems like a separate issue, that would be better presented as a separate question...